# Azure Portal - right click context menu not showing

Tags: azure, menu

According to this Microsoft guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create
when right-clicking a web job, there should be a context menu.  However, no menu appears when I right-click on a web-job.  I am not seeing any context menus when right-clicking on elements in the Azure portal.  So two questions along the same line:

1. How do I get the right click / context menu to appear when right clicking a web job in the azure portal?
2. Are there other elements that should have a context menu within the Azure portal when right clicking them?

Comment: How you have deployed your WebApp ?

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the web job context menu.

Comment: for me, click on the job to highlight it, the options shown to be a context menu on the (maybe out of date?) help pages are above the list (next to add)

Comment: Right click won't work in Azure Portal Web Job.The option to add web job will be available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfNDI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the document the optionS available on right click are `Logs`, `Delete`,`Stop` and `Properties`.

***Image from Document:***

> [image]

> no menu appears when I right-click on a web-job.

Thanks @TZHX for the comment.

As mentioned by TZHX may be the UI must have changed.

Even I didn't find option to right click on the Web Jobs.

The `Logs` and `Delete` option is available in the created Job List itself.

[image]

I have referred this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/continuous?view=azure-cli-latest)
to stop a WebJob.

As an alternative to `Stop` a `Web Job`  we can use `Azure CLI` command.

```
az webapp webjob continuous stop --name AppInsightsWebJob --resource-group YourResourceGroup --webjob-name MyJob
```

[image]

[image]

- Starting a WebJob  option is available in `Run`.

[image]